# LastPass Enterprise API New User Request

Tags: powershell, lastpass

I am trying to use the LastPass Enterprise API to automate the creation of new users in our system using Powershell. I cannot seem to get the call to the API correct in my code. I am almost certain it has something to do with the "data" object. This is the batch object I am passing through the body.

```
$lastPassObject = @{
      cid = "G1TUROWN";
      provhash = "N0TM!NE";
      cmd = "batchadd";
      data = @(
        {          
          username = $email;
          fullname = $firstName + " " + $lastName;
          password = "Toys4Trucks22!";
          password_reset_required = "true";
        } 
      )
  }
```

Here is my API call

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://lastpass.com/enterpriseapi.php" -Method Post -Body $lastPassObject -ContentType "application/json"
```

Followed by the Error I am receiving

[image: Error Message]

Reference to the API: https://support.lastpass.com/help/add-new-users-via-lastpass-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your body to json before sending it.
Also, you put your `Data` section in a scriptblock within an array.
This need to be a hashtable, not a scriptblock.

```
$lastPassObject = @{
      cid = "G1TUROWN";
      provhash = "N0TM!NE";
      cmd = "batchadd";
      data = @(
# This need to be an hashtable. You were missing the @
        @{          
          username = $email;
          fullname = $firstName + " " + $lastName;
          password = "Toys4Trucks22!";
          password_reset_required = $true;
        } 
      )
  }

$Body = $lastPassObject | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://lastpass.com/enterpriseapi.php" -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"
```

If you still have issues after that, make sure to check what the actual json look like (after `ConvertTo-Json`) so you know exactly what you are sending and can spot more easily discrepancies. For instance, when I first did it, I immediately saw that the data section was all wrong, formatting wise and spotted the missing `@` because of that.

Also, still by looking at the converted json and the example from their doc, you can see that `password_reset_required` is a boolean. I changed your `"true"` to `$true` so that the correlating json would be what was expected.

Comment: Awesome this seemed to work perfectly. I did not know that adding the @ in front of the curly braces would make that section of code a hashtable. I will try converting and reviewing my requests in JSON in the future. If you don't mind me asking, would you recommend learning more about hash tables? They appear to be prevalent in a lot of API calls that send a lot of data.

Comment: @RankinJ Just curly braces didn't gives error because that is also a Powershell construct, the scriptblock. Check the official documentation to start with. [about_hash_tabless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) and [about_Script_Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2). This will help you understand both and differences between the two :)

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for your help and some of your insight on Powershell.